# is there object generator working on JSON ? (just like XSDObjectGen.exe)

Tags: .net, asp.net, json, xsdobjectgen

I have to serialize & desserialize  json data.

if the data type was XSD, I am able to  create class  by using XSDObjectGen.exe

But ,

the data type I have to serialize  is 'JSON'.

Is there any good way to generate class for serialize & deserialize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `JSONDataSerializer`, but it is some obscure assembly. (Maybe the ASP.NET extensions?)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

...

JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string payload = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(myObject);
//or
string payload = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(new object[] { myObject.Id });
```